# How to install Propel on a normal hosting account?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, propel

I'm on the propel website now (http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.5/Installation), and as I expected, there's a lot of command-line instructions for installing it, but how do I get it to work on my www.winhost.com server? Do I just upload the propel folder, and that's it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download the tarball available at the download page (http://files.propelorm.org/propel-1.5.5.tar.gz) and extract it on your web space. More instructions can be found in the tarball in the INSTALL file :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't run a command line on your server, you can generate the model files on your local computer and upload them. You only need the `runtime` part of the Propel installation on your server, the `generator` part is only used for creating the files.